# How do I use Scanner Delimiter to eliminate groups of chars without removing the char completely?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I'm trying to rid my scans of special symbols and fractions like "1/4" with out eliminating whole ints such as "1".  When I input the code below it not only removes my fractions with 1 as a numerator but also the one at the beginning.  Is there any way around this?

`Scanner sc2 = new Scanner("1.How many cups do I need?(You need 1/4)");
            sc2.useDelimiter("[?.! ()\\s*1/\\s*]+");`

Answer (score 0):

just remove **1** on your pattern in delimiter:

```
sc2.useDelimiter("[?.! ()\\s*1/\\s*]+")
```

to

```
sc2.useDelimiter("[?.! ()\\s*/\\s*]+") // remove 1
```

Comment: however if I removed only the / wouldn't i end up with two 1s and a 4

Comment: what would be your desired output ?

Comment: to have only a remainder of "1" "How" "many" "cups" "do" "I" "need" "You" "need"